# Give when you can't see a violent raise

Tags: dogs-in-the-vineyard

I just have read the Dogs in the Vineyard rulebook, and I have a question regarding conflict resolution.

If there is a conflict between two characters, and at some point one escalates from talking to gun fighting, adding the dice from the gun and raising with an 14 (for example), firing at the opponent. If the opponent can't see the raise, he has to give the fight, and therefore I choose the outcome of the conflict. But what happens to that raise I had made? Does he take the blow with all his remaining dice, or do I choose that, too?

English is not my native language, so maybe it's explained in the text, but I haven't been able to understand it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Treat it as though your opponent had blocked or dodged your raise. You get the stakes, but your opponent gets to block or dodge your last raise for free.

Answer (score 7):

Let's say you are fighting over a precious vase: the GM raises a 19 and says "he pulls out the gun and shoots you in the kidney." You respond "No way: I throw the vase at him so he has to get it," giving the conflict and parrying the raise.

Page 64:

> Giving
>
> When you Give instead of Seeing, you don’t need to Take the Blow. In fact, one of the best reasons to Give is to avoid a Blow you can’t bear to Take. There’s no need to stay in a conflict to the bitter end. You can and should Give as soon as your character would, 
>   as soon as you’re willing to let the conflict go — be it because the stakes aren’t worth it, or because you’ve thought of follow-up stakes even better — or as soon as you realize you can’t win.
>
> When you Give instead of Raising, you get to cut your losses. Grab your highest remaining single die and set it aside. If there’s any follow-up conflict, roll your Stat and Relationship dice as usual, then add this reserved die to the mix. Don’t reroll it! This represents the advantage you keep by ceding the previous stakes on your own terms.

Comment: Ciao Domon and welcome to StackExchange! I'm afraid that, while Vincent is the author of the game and as a primary source his word is to be trusted, it'd be better if you made a page reference to the text supporting your answer, be it in the rules or in some forum.

Comment: Done! it that ok?